# Generic way to get primary key from declaratively defined instance in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Does SQLAlchemy offer a *generic* way to get the primary key from a declaratively defined instance, so that if:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I can do:

```
>>> a = MyClass(key=1)
>>> a.generic_get_primary_key()  # <-- does it exist ??
1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `inspection` for that purpose:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html

Passing an instance of a mapped object to inspect, returns an `InstanceState`, describing that object.
This state also contains the identity:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
a = MyClass(key=1)

from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect    
pk = inspect(a).identity
print pk
```

Will give:

```
(1,)
```

Since primary keys can consist of multiple columns, the identity in general is a tuple containing all the column values that are part of the primary key.
In your case, that's simply the `key`.

Comment: This is not working anymore with `sqlalchemy >= 1.0`

Comment: @flazzarini It does work with `sqlalchemy >= 1.0` and it is well documented: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState.identity It only seems to differ from what you want to do.

Comment: Note that `inspect(a).identity` is `None` when the instance is "transient" or "pending": https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState.identity

Answer (score 13):

If you need to retrieve a list primary keys of a `class` not an `instance` the following describes how to do it.

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/inspection.html) method. This will return an `Inspect` instance on which you can do your analysis as follows. In this example I use the `Inspect` instance to return to me all `attribute` names of each primary_key of `MyClass`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "myclass"

    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)



from sqlalchemy import inspect
ins = inspect(MyClass)
print("Tuple of primary keys: ", ins.primary_key)

# Let's loop over them and print the attribute key name of each
for x in ins.primary_key:
    print(x.key)
```

Returns

```
> Tuple of primary keys:  (Column('key', Integer(), table=<myclass>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('name', String(), table=<myclass>, primary_key=True, nullable=False))
> key
> name
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. The original question was how to retrieve the primary keys' "value" for a certain mapped **instance**, while you're retrieving the columns that make up the primary key for a mapped **class**.

Comment: Exactly, so I changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by getting the primary key name and next, with getattr, passing the class instance and the name of primary key like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXu0T.png)

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

# I use this class for all my tables in sqlalchemy
class BaseTablesClass():
    # First I get the name of the primary key, just the first value of array because 
    # a table can have more than a primary key

    def primary_key_name(self):
        return inspect(self).primary_key[0].name

    # Next in this line I get the value of primary key by the name that I get with the
    # method of primary key name
    def primary_key_value(self):
        return getattr(self, self.primary_key_name())
```

Answer (score -1):

Use inspect function:

```py
inspect(obj).identity
```

This will work include "transient" and "pending":

```py
inspect(obj.__class__).primary_key_from_instance(obj)
```