# Retrieve arbitrary PK from db model

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have a model with PK, lets say `device_id` (so it's not `id`) which I relate in another table:

`x =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('device.device_id'))`

How can I reference this column in sqlalchemy query?

In Django I could use `Device.pk` and it would resolve the PK. Is this possible in flask with sqlalchemy?

Comment: Here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32200462/1377864).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either join it, or use a relationship for SQLAlchemy to work it's magic automatically.

It looks like you're talking about a Many to One relationship, so, [using the documentation example](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#one-to-many-relationships):

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

If the PK was named differently on the Person, you would just adjust the `ForeignKey` to match:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    toot = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.toot'))
```

If I then wanted to find out all `Person` objects who have an email address of `test@example.com` I could just say:

```
Person.query.join(Address).filter(Address.email='test@example.com').all()
```